# How to get filtered Table values in PowerBI on changing date parameter

Tags: filter, powerbi

I have 'Transaction' table as below

[image]

A date table as below

[image]

And an inventory table as below.

[image]

The Inventory table has dates ranging from last 2 years.

How do I get a new column in my Transaction table, which will be dynamic on the date filter, giving me the inventory count of the earliest date in the filter.

[image]

So in this case, I want the inventory count 20180511 for the matching Bookkey.

Transaction and Inventory tables has distinct Bookkey level information

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Calculated columns cannot be dynamic/responsive to slicers since they are computed only once per data refresh.

You can use measures to create dynamic calculations in report visuals though.

Comment: Can you help with calculating a measure for this?

Comment: Probably, as long as you can explain what you want your visual to look like.

Comment: Yes. I am thinking or creating a table view. The columns are going to be BookKey, Sales and Inventory, there will be another date slicer. The Inventory column will have Inventory values from Inventory table at the earliest date of the slicer. I am thinking of this measure `Earliest invetory = SUMX(FILTER(Inventory,Inventory[FileDate]=[Earliest_date]),Inventory[CurInvUsed])` where `Earliest_date = MIN(Inventory[FileDate])`

Does it seem correct?

Comment: This worked :D 
`Earliest invetory = CALCULATE(SUM(Inventory[CurInvUsed]),FILTER(Inventory,Inventory[FileDate] IN {MIN(Inventory[FileDate])}))`