# about in-memory mode working logic in power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

When going through DAX overview documentation on the following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/dax-overview,

under the Calculated Column heading, I couldn't understand the highlighted information in the following statement:

"(calculated) Column values are only recalculated if the table or any related table is processed (refresh) or the model is unloaded from memory and then reloaded, like when closing and reopening a Power BI Desktop file."

Does it mean, that whenever we close the Power BI Desktop file, the model is unloaded from memory? does the memory is used like Cache?

Would anyone please help me understand what actually happens in practical world? Thank you for giving your valuable time and support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main point of this remark is to distinguish the [difference between measures and calculated columns](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/calculated-columns-and-measures-in-dax/) since the distinction is often [not clear to report builders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52562414).

A measure is dynamically calculated on-demand when the end-user interacts with the report via slicers or any other sort of filtering and interaction.

A calculated column is *only* calculated when the model is refreshed. As a result, calculated columns cannot be dynamically responsive to the end-user since they have already been computed before the user can interact with the report.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand, Alex

Answer (score 0):

Power BI Desktop is excel on steraloids. It is an application and as with every application when you close it, it unloads from memory. Its great and you can do a lot..
It has the option to refresh (a button) when you press it, it recalculates your calculated columns.

If you want dashboards and reports served, to be shown in other (web) applications. You want to go with Power BI server. It runs in the cloud and you can refresh the data (daily, on the hour or direct) you can set this all up scheduled in the admin tools.

It is logical that only on a refresh, your calculated columns get recalculated. Only in this moment of time your raw data is changing what will have effect on your calculated columns.

Comment: Thanks Dharman & Aldert for your support!